# jQuery event triggers

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I have a select box with an onchange listener.  This functions 100% when human uses it.

I've added a modal dialog with jQueryUI to create a new option on to said list.
This works 100% as well.

However, Upon adding said new option to the list, I am trying to 'fake' the change event to trigger so the user doesn't have to do it.   It never seems to fire.

Can I use the trigger like this?

```
//##### ADDC ####//
$( "#add" ).click(function(){
    $( "#addform" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 200,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function() { 
                var f = $('#folder').val();
                var request = $.ajax({  
                    url: "process.it"
                    ,  type: "POST"
                    ,  data: {  f  : f   }
                });                 
                request.done(function(msg) {
                    $("#version").append( $('<option></option>').val(msg).html(msg) ).val(msg);
                    $("#version").focus();
                });
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );    
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $('#version').trigger('change');
        }
    }); 
    return false; 
});



//###### CHANGE ###############
$('#version').change(function() {       
    var promise = getFolders(mypath);
    promise.success(function (data) {
        promise.done(function(msg) {        
            if(msg=="false"){
                //error check   
            } else {
                var myOptions = msg.split(",");
                var mySelect = $('#version');

                mySelect
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end();
                $.each(myOptions, function(x,y) {
                    if(x==0){
                        x=-1;
                        y="Select Version";
                        mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(x).html(y));
                    }
                    else {      
                        mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(y).html(y));
                    }
                }); 
                mySelect.focus();
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

I've pulled out a TON of code, so if there's so brackets out of place, its simply typos here to show the core of the function.  Again, both work save for the adder calling the changer:

The key line is:

```
close: function() {
            $('#version').trigger('change');
        }
```

html looks like

```
  <select id="version"></select>  <a href="#" id="add">
```

When the modal closes (or other place), I want it to fire the onchange to effectively re-pull from source (the promise ajax lookup, function not listed here...) instead of what it does now, which is simply append the option to the list and select it.

I've tried this trigger block of code in a could places and it still won't fire.

So, how do I fake the onchange from the system?  I'm using a modern build of both jQuery and UI (maybe 1 point release out)

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the change after the request is done?

Comment: yes, upon adding the new option, I want the change event to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are triggering the change before the response from the server. If you want to trigger the change after the, have your add method close the dialog in the 'done' function.

```
 buttons: {
        "Add": function() { 
            var f = $('#folder').val();
            var request = $.ajax({  
                url: "process.it"
                ,  type: "POST"
                ,  data: {  f  : f   }
            });                 
            request.done(function(msg) {
                $("#version").append( $('<option></option>').val(msg).html(msg) ).val(msg);
                $("#version").focus();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );  
            });

        },
```

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/AMZ3n/2/

Comment: yup.  I had a 'race condition'  adding an alert in where i had it also allowed it to show.   Moving it to the done did the trick.  thanks!